# Daily Star Bonus - How Much is it and How Much Does it Increment?

Tags: clash-of-clans

Following the most recent update the new feature of a daily star bonus has been made available. The news bulletin claims that you 'Earn bigger bonuses at higher leagues!'.

How much is earned in each league, and how much more can be earned as a result of climbing the league ladder?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The star bonus for each league is as follows.

```
 - Titan III - Legend: 360000 gold and elixir + 1800 dark elixir

 - Champion I: 340000 gold and elixir + 1700 dark elixir

 - Champion II: 320000 gold and elixir + 1600 dark elixir

 - Champion III: 300000 gold and elixir + 1500 dark elixir

 - Masters I: 280000 gold and elixir + 1400 dark elixir

 - Masters II: 260000 gold and elixir + 1300 dark elixir

 - Masters III: 240000 gold and elixir + 1200 dark elixir

 - Crystal I: 220000 gold and elixir + 1100 dark elixir

 - Crystal II: 200000 gold and elixir + 1000 dark elixir

 - Crystal III: 180000 gold and elixir + 800 dark elixir

 - Gold I: 160000 gold and elixir + 600 dark elixir

 - Gold II: 140000 gold and elixir + 400 dark elixir

 - Gold III: 120000 gold and elixir + 200 dark elixir

 - Silver I: 100000 gold and elixir 

 - Silver II: 90000 gold and elixir

 - Silver III: 80000 gold and elixir

 - Bronze I: 70000 gold and elixir

 - Bronze II: 60000 gold and elixir

 - Bronze III: 50000 gold and elixir
```